# Why RPC-like instead of RESTful?

Tags: api-design

I wonder why for Ethereum Web3 API (and for Bitcoind as well) the choice for the remote API has been on RPC style instead of RESTful. In principle REST is driven by data models while RPC is driven by actions, so I assume that the designers found a node much more "someone" to send command, rather than a set of resources to be accessed with CRUD (Create Read Update Delete) patterns. However, I'd like to find some prior discussion on that if any available on the fora.